# Datatable not refreshig on server side search

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

This is how I have declared my datatable

```
 $('#editable').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
             "serverSide": true,
             "ajax": "ProjectController.php?getProjectData=1",
```

When I type in the search bar the call goes off and retrieves the correct data however the table does not change. 
Is there any setting that I have to do to correct this?

The returned json is

```js
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": "2",
  "recordsFiltered": 2,
  "data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "jobnumber": "",
    "name": "Piek, G D F",
    "erfno": "block 46",
    "address": null,
    "from": null,
    "jobyear": "1995",
    "jobstatus": "Complete",
    "contactinfo": null,
    "datedue": null,
    "datecreated": "2010-06-29 14:38:49",
    "operatorname": null
  }, {
    "id": "63658",
    "jobnumber": "",
    "name": "Piek, G D F",
    "erfno": "block 46",
    "address": null,
    "from": null,
    "jobyear": "1995",
    "jobstatus": "Complete",
    "contactinfo": null,
    "datedue": null,
    "datecreated": "2010-06-29 14:38:49",
    "operatorname": null
  }]
}
```

Comment: did you check what is returning from your call?

Comment: Yes it is returning the correct data

Comment: Are you sure it's returning _filtered_ data? If it's not actually filtering then it would look like the table hasn't changed.

Comment: I even forced it to sent back the same data when it first loads and it draws the table prefectly

Comment: Got it you need to increase the draw count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it you need to increase the draw count in the json that you send back to the table